# C# Desktop application getting notification when any updates adding new ad in usedcar web page like

Tags: c#, web-applications, notifications, updates, windows

I want to create a desktop application for a usedcarsale website . When new ad is updated then the application should notify that to me . How can i do it ?

Comment: Where is the ad being updated, on the website or the desktop app? How are the updates being stored? What do mean by "notify me"? Is "me" an application or do you mean you want an email or SMS message?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like show `taskbar notifications` in notification area and slide away after a few seconds, these two articles from "Code Project" might be useful for you.

- [NotifyWindow](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7853/NotifyWindow-A-different-MSN-Messenger-style-notif) may be easier to use if you just intend to display
  text.
- If you want to display your own images in the notification window,
  you may prefer to use John O'Byrne's [TaskbarNotifier](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3285/TaskbarNotifier-a-skinnable-MSN-Messenger-like-pop).